# Check if a method is being executed during runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to check if a particular method is being executed at a particular point of time on iOS ?

For example, I want to know if the method *sampleMethod* is being run at 1 minute after the app starts executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use _cmd for that?

```
NSLog(@"Method name = %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

Comment: I tried adding **if ([NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]) {
    NSLog(@"Yes");
}** in my method. It worked ! Yours works too. Thanks. +1

Comment: Is it possible to find this while another method is being executed? For eg, Method *b* is running and i want to know if method *a* is being run.

Comment: @user2229411 No problem! Only one method will be running at that particular moment though?

Comment: Even in the case of multi-threading? please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @user2229411 Multithreading doesn't mean that there are indeed more functions running at the same time. They're just being switched over continuously.

Answer (score 1):

Using breakpoints and/or the `NSLog(NSString)` function inside your mehthods.